# Refresh parent page upon closing child with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following function being called on the child page pop-up from the main page. The function:

```
function getBenefitEdit(bfn_benefit, bfn_benefit_id, bfn_std_max_days, bfn_std_pcy_wait_days){
    document.forms[0].std_benefit_nm_policy_chg.value = bfn_benefit;
    document.forms[0].std_benefit_id_policy_chg.value = bfn_benefit_id;
    document.forms[0].std_max_days_policy_chg.value = bfn_std_max_days;
    document.forms[0].std_pcy_wait_days_policy_chg.value = bfn_std_pcy_wait_days;  
          document.forms[0].action = "nwrGetBenefitSTD.do";            
          document.forms[0].submit();
          window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
          window.close(); 
        }
```

I'm trying to get the new page to update the parent page, then refresh the parent page upon closing it. Unfortunately, while this works in FireFox, it fails in IE. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try calling the `window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;` line **before** the `document.forms[0].submit();` line. Not sure if that will fix anything, but worth a shot.

Comment: Believe it or not, this was the most useful suggestion! That fixed the issue entirely.

Comment: Cool, I added an answer for the heck of it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why it's not working in IE, but you could use this instead:

```
window.opener.location.reload();
```

[Update] what you could also do is attach the reload to the [onsubmit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onsubmit) event handler.

Comment: This worked, but only with the moving up of the line to above the `document.forms[0].submit();` line. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the few lines at the end in this order:

```
window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
document.forms[0].submit();
window.close();
```

I'm guessing that in IE (or whatever browser it won't work in), when the form is submitted (the page being left), it will not allow communication with the opener.